# How to create buffer on one side of a stream in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I need to create a buffer around waterfront park sites. But I only want "half" of the buffer --- the "half" that coincides with the side of the water body where to park is.

In addition, the buffer of one park may overlap another due to their proximity. I would like to have just one "half" buffer for each park.

I tried to buffer the parks, union them with waterbody, erase waterbody, select by location the buffer using the parks. But since the buffers overlap, they create multipart features and only one or two parts of the buffer are selected.

Below is example of what I am talking about.

For the park (green) on the left I would like a half buffer to the north (assuming north is up) and no buffer south of the waterbody.

For the parks on the right (one big and one small) I would like two separate buffers that are each single part features.

ps these are both polygon vector files and I have an advanced license

[image]

EDIT:
@ChrisW s method:
[image]

Comment: How proportionally wide are these buffers in relation to average width of the main river?  Double or triple the width?  I would draw a line down the approximate center of the river and create a left/right hand buffer of the line (which buffer will do). Make the buffer wide enough to at least touch every buffer that could cross the river, and preferably entire cover every future buffer.  Attribute left vs. right buffer and spatial join to polygons.  Buffer those polygons and erase the buffer on the side opposite the attribute, then erase the river itself.  Should leave buffers on one side.

Comment: You can specify right or left side in the buffer tool in ArcToolbox. This does not work with the Buffer dropdown on the Editor toolbar. You can specify Outside only as well.

Comment: Do it with the tool.  You only need left and right side buffers for the entire river centerline to be created once, not for any of the polygons along the river.  You have to create a special line feature type to make this work.  (rest of post erased.  I though recurvata's comment was from the original post author).

Comment: @Richard Fairhurst Cool, i did not know about left/right buffer, but I don't think it will work. The streams vary a lot in width and there are parks adjacent to ocean, which would not have a centerline to buffer around

Comment: A coastline can have a centerline (all centerlines are imaginary 2D human constructs, and none actually exist in nature, so make one anywhere in the world you want one).  The centerline just has to stay inside the river/ocean boundary off land. Put each line's buffer width in a field to vary the widths.  Adjust each centerline buffer width enough to cross the river edge or coastline on to land on each side.  Erase the river first then select any park polygon that spatial joined the left buffer with the line right buffer and vice versa and deleted it.  All wrong side polys will touch it.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst Perhaps you should turn your comments into an answer. It's certainly a viable alternative to my solution, depending on how large the data set is and how many 'centerlines' would have to be created (perhaps that could be done automatically?).

Comment: Have a look on ArcScripts or ArcGIS Online gallery. I found this [tool](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13301).

Comment: could you provide more information, like the siez of the park an the size of the rivers + are you only looking at parks adjacent to the river + draw by hand what you expect as a result

Answer (score 2):

1. Buffer the parks the desired distance with Dissolve type set to
   NONE. You should have individual buffers for each park.
2. Erase the waterbody layer from the buffers. Erase requires an
   Advanced license, but you've already mentioned using it.
3. Explode or Multiparts to singleparts the remaining buffers. This
   splits any multipart features where a buffer was so large it went
   all the way across and beyond the river.
4. Select by location all buffers that do not intersect a park and
   delete them. These are those across the river pieces. Some of them
   won't get selected in cases like that tiny park on the north side
   east end of your image.
5. Open the buffer attribute table and examine the buffer/feature ID
   (the attribute that gives the ID for the feature it was created
   from). Either by sorting the table on that field, or using a
   summarize with a count on it (or Summary Statistics if you want a
   separate table to look at) determine which of the original buffers
   still have more than one piece. You'll know because there will be
   two rows/records with the same ID. Hopefully there aren't too many
   of them, and you can visit each and delete the appropriate one. If there are a lot or for a more automated approach you'd be looking to select all buffers where they intersect a park and the ID doesn't match.

Comment: If he has an advanced license, he can just use the Left or Right option for the line side.

Comment: @crmackey no, he cannot, because his river is a polygon and left/right is only valid for lines. He would first have to convert the river polygons or ocean to lines, or draw a line to use. Comments have already stated this is not feasible.

Comment: No one has said it is infeasible that I can see.  The lines need not be accurate in any way other than that they stay inside the river.  An LR network also should be part of his tool set if he wants to monitor any events on his rivers (Polygons suck for that, as proven by the fact that I could never keep up by using road casings to track events on my road network, but can easily with LR).  If this is a primary assignment then everything becomes feasible when we get tired of doing too many manual steps over and over and decide to put the time into things that save time in the long run.

Comment: @ChrisW I tried what you mentioned. When I select by location all buffers that dont touch the park, I only get some of the single part features of the buffer because so many of them overlap. I inserted a picture of that in the original post.

Comment: @ChrisW also my "parks" file is not finalized and I will most likely be adding and deleting from it. So an automated model would be a lot more ideal than manually sifting through the attribute table

Comment: @OliverOliver Something does not look right with that output. Is the buffer distance variable? You've got a lot of white north of the river that shouldn't be there and the visible boundaries between buffers don't make sense. It looks like the buffers have been clipped or intersected with themselves or something. Also, are you *only* wanting waterfront parks to be buffered, or *all* parks? Would it be possible to post the two layers somewhere so we can test on them? If we can get the geometry part figured out, we can look at automating that last step - this could all be turned into a model.